# CSS3 PIE border overlap

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, css3pie

Has anyone come across this border overlap with border-radius and css3pie?

I'm seeing this in windows XP IE8.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot graphic is intriguing but insufficient for us to offer any suggestions. If you want any serious help, you'll need to show us the code that causes this. Preferably a live demo using http://jsbin.com or similar. Also, what version of CSS3Pie are you using? And have you checked the css3pie forums to see if anyone else has had a similar problem?

Comment: I have checked the PIE forums and no luck, something similar but not quite the same. I'll setup a demo now and report back.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to add a small border radius to the problem corners

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bug https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/11 -- it is fixed in the 2.0 beta so you could try that.